# Generic collection of MenuItems in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, drop-down-menu

I am working on displaying a list of audio input devices in the menu, and I'm fairly new to C#.  The number of input devices not only varies from machine to machine, it is possible that someone might add or subtract a USB device while the program is running.  I wrote code that checks whenever the menu is activated, but I have to limit the number of possible input devices.  It's not likely that there will be more than 10 input devices, but, in order to understand C# better, I'd like to see if it's possible to use a generic so that I don't have to limit the list.

Here's what I have going for code now:

```
MainMenu sgFileMenu = new MainMenu(); 
List<MenuItem> inputDevice = new List<MenuItem>();

MenuItem myMenuItemInput = new MenuItem("&Input Devices");
sgFileMenu.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemInput);

for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
{
    myMenuItemInput.MenuItems.Add(inputDevice[i]);
}
```

That compiles but gives an ArgumentOutOfRange exception when I run it.  I'm obviously missing something about how generics are set up- can somebody clue me in?

Added after reading some of the comments- deviceCount is an integer and is not 0- that's checked someplace else.  It seems clear that I need to do something before:

```
    myMenuItemInput.MenuItems.Add(inputDevice[i]);
```

But I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Does it iterate even once?  Check the length of your list before the loop and that will tell you which part has the issue.

Comment: @M.Babcock if you set `i <= deviceCount` you'll end out of bounds.

Comment: @M.Babcock no, his problem is that inputDevice is an empty list, and probably deviceCount is grater than zero.

Comment: @pinckerman - Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputDevice.Count; i++)
{
    myMenuItemInput.MenuItems.Add(inputDevice[i]);
}
```

Anyway, you've initialized `inputDevice` as an empty list, so it doesn't contain any `MenuItem`.

Comment: deviceCount is a positive integer, that's not where the problem is.  How do I initialize inputDevice as a list with MenuItems in it?  That's what I'm missing.

Comment: You've initialized it correctly. You're missing adding elements in it. Simply call `inputDevice.Add(new MenuItem(...));`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with generics.  I'm guessing `deviceCount` is some number other than 0.  Since you initialize `inputDevice` but never actually add anything to it, it stays empty, and `inputDevice[i]` will throw that exception.